# Occurrence of Invariant Violation while running the app using expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

There has been three error which is surfacing while i bundle the application

1. Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNPermissionsModule' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes
2. Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.

3. A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
   [Terminal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj69I.png)

[Emulator Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U252s.png)

I've tried upgrading the expo version
I've tried using "AppRegistry" from "react-native" library.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.